# Bootstrap 4 dropdown alignment to parent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap dropdown as part of input group. How do I align width of the dropdown-menu to parent's input-group?

```
 <div id="ddl_1" class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control ">

   <div class="input-group-append">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
             aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" 
             data-toggle="dropdown" 
             data-boundary="viewport" 
             data-reference="parent" 
             data-target="#ddl_1">
     </button>
     <div class="dropdown-menu">
       <div class="dropdown-item">Name 0</div>
       <div class="dropdown-item">Name 1</div>
       <div class="dropdown-item">Name 2</div>
       <div class="dropdown-item">Name 3</div>
       <div class="dropdown-item">Name 4</div>
     </div>
     
   </div>
 </div><!-- end input group -->
```

Note, that I'm using `data-boundary="viewport"` because I use it  inside scrollable container and it might overflow.

https://codepen.io/Lieroo/pen/JjKadpa

Answer (score 0):

You can change the "position-static" of the "input-group" div to "position-relative". Then you add "w-100" to the "dropdown-menu" div.

```
 <div id="ddl_1" class="input-group position-relative show">
   <input type="text" class="form-control ">

   <div class="input-group-append">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
             aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" 
             data-toggle="dropdown" 
             data-boundary="viewport" 
             data-reference="parent" 
             data-target="#ddl_1">
     </button>
     <div class="dropdown-menu w-100">
       <div class="dropdown-item">Name 0</div>
       <div class="dropdown-item">Name 1</div>
       <div class="dropdown-item">Name 2</div>
       <div class="dropdown-item">Name 3</div>
       <div class="dropdown-item">Name 4</div>
     </div>
     
   </div>
 </div><!-- end input group -->
```

https://codepen.io/callmesupercookie/pen/MWeqaeX

Comment: position-static is added automatically by bootstrap javascript, when I use data-boudary="viewport". By explicitelly marking it as position-relative, you broke the requirement, that is must overflow the container.